# Scraped Results Not Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, whenever

I am scheduling via the Whenever gem, however, it seems that my scraped results are not getting updated at all.

I think it's because it's being saved (i.e., the earlier results), so it's displaying those results only but I'm not sure.

Controller:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController

 
def index
  @entries = Entry.all
end

def scrape

    RedditScrapper.scrape

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

lib/reddit_scrapper.rb:

```
require 'open-uri'

module RedditScrapper
  def self.scrape
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entriesArray = []
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      entriesArray << Entry.new({ title: title, link: link })
    end

    if entriesArray.map(&:valid?)
      entriesArray.map(&:save!)
    end
  end
end
```

config/schedule.rb:

```
RAILS_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/')

every 2.minutes do 
  runner "RedditScrapper.scrape", :environment => "development"
end
```

model:

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord

end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    #root 'entry#scrape_reddit'
    root 'entries#index'
    resources :entries
    #get '/new_entries', to: 'entries#scrape', as: 'scrape'
end
```

View index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Reddit's Front Page</h1>
<% @entries.order("created_at DESC").limit(10).each do |entry| %>
  <h3><%= entry.title %></h3>
  <p><%= entry.link %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just `Entry.create!` to create an entry:

```
module RedditScraper
  def self.scrape
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entriesArray = []
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      Entry.create!(title: title, link: link )
    end
  end
end
```

To get 10 latest entries:

```
# controller
def index
  @entries = Entry.order("created_at DESC").limit(10)
end
```

view:

<% @entries.each do |entry| %>

But too think you need change the order of parsing items from Reddit for the latest in the top but you add it first to database. You need to make a change in the Reddit **scraper** .

Revert entries: instead of

```
entries.each do |entry|
```

use

```
entries.revert.each do |entry|
```

so, parsing will start from the end of entries and latest news will be added in the end.

Comment: would you know how to get the last 10 most recent posts? I wrote the code for it, but it doesn't seem to be matching Reddit's first 10 top results ... have posted the updated `view` code in my post above ... sorry, can't create another question as it limits you to 6 questions in 24 hours (a first for me ever!) ...

Comment: If you're getting locked because you've asked 6 questions in 24 hours, then “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" would be important to read. Your questions asked rarely get up voted which indicates they're not well asked and/or are not very useful. I'd recommend trying to answer more questions too as your Q to A ratio is quite skewed. Remember, SO is not a "give me help" site, it's a "here's a tough question others will have in the future so let's collect solutions" reference site.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 the answer is updated with 10 top results. Forgot add comment about that)

Comment: @theTinMan ... um ... ok ... are you going through all my questions? am I that bad? ... and my questions are not coming from the place of "please give me ans as I can't be bothered to google it and/or figure it out" ... it's genuinely coming from a place of trying to figure it out ... and yes, my ratio is quite skewed because I don't want to contribute ill-informed answers.

Comment: @AlexKojin, thank you. Will check into it later it as I have work to finish right now. Will update you asap.

Comment: @theTinMan, also I didn't realize that because a question is not upvoted that it's an indicator of its quality. Thought it was part and parcel of Q&A site to have questions that doesn't have to be upvoted. My concern when asking question is to make it clear as possible to resolve it.

Comment: I'm not looking for your questions. You ask a lot of questions in areas I specialize in so you're putting them where I run into them. Upvotes are a direct indication of the quality and usefulness of the question. Hovering over the up-vote arrow displays "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" whereas the down-vote arrow displays "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Questions get fewer votes than answers but 0 for questions that have existed for a while tells us something.

Comment: @theTinMan, Ah ok. Well, I'm suddenly asking more questions than I normally do, hence why you're running into them. Really trying to finally learn ROR on a more consistent basis. Thank you for challenging me to think more about how I'm asking my questions. I don't necessarily actually agree with the voting of the questions because I've seen it be inconsistent, and not always due to "quality" of the question one way or other. I've seen questions downvoted, and upvoted until it's balanced out. It's life. It's why I never take it personally one way or other on voting of my questions.

Comment: @theTinMan, My primary end goal is to resolve my questions and hopefully learn from it long term wise this time. But you do also have a point that my Q&A are skewed towards me asking questions primarily. And I have said that I didn't want to contribute ill-informed answers. But I'll try to answer more ... and hopefully, well-informed answers. It's another good way to learn more ROR. So, thank you for that as well.

Comment: Valid reasons, and I'm glad you understand the SO model better. Too many don't have a clue nor seem to want to learn. Answering questions is an even better way to learn than asking questions; You'll find you do a lot of research initially.